# Is this sequence uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_t\colon [0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f_t(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2(1+\alpha(1-x_1^{1/t})(1-x_2^{1/t}))^t.$

Here $-1\leq\alpha\leq 1$ is a constant. Then $f_t$ converges pointwise to $x_1x_2$. My question is, if it also converges uniformly?

Comment: I assume by the $x-x_2^{1/t}$ you mean $1-x_2^{1/t}$, right?

Comment: Math1000, yes I did, thanks. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Do you know anything about the monotonicity?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the sequence f_t converges monotonically towards $x_1x_2$ (increasingly for $\alpha<0$ and decreasingly for $\alpha>0$). For instance, if $\delta>0$, and $t_1<t_2$, then $1-x_1^{1/t_1}>1-x_1^{1/t_2}$, and hence $(1+\alpha(1-x_1^{1/t_1})(1-x_2^{1/t_1}))^{t_1}>(1+\alpha(1-x_1^{1/t_2})(1-x_2^{1/t_2}))^{t_2}$. Is monotonicity of any help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

So it seems the convergence is uniform

Comment: Thank you, Pelto, this theorem does seem like what I need!